# Storing multiple objects for a user in a DB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

Building this application requires data like the below.

- User: `{name: 'Mike', email: 'whatevs@gmail.com', password:
  '$78*#&84'}`
- Website: `{owner: 'Mike', website: 'ma', structure: {body: {header: {}, main: {}, footer: {}}}}`
- Works: `{owner: 'Mike', collection: [{title: 'nice', img_src: 'lol.jpg'}]}`

The data above is a rough schema of what I am about to create.

What would be a good practice in terms of storing this data? I am so much more familiar with MongoDB than anything, but I feel like it's time to adopt SQL.

I am asking because being so familiar with MongoDB I know its not relational and may be a headache to map the data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is relational here are your tables

User

- userID
- email
- password

website

- websiteID
- ownerUserID
- sitename

website_structure

- websiteID
- body
- header
- main
- footer

works

- userid
- collectionID

collection

- collectionID
- title
- img_src

Just break the bits down and relate them by ids where they are nodes in your schema

Comment: But couldn't I do this with a document based DB like mongoDB?